# Converter um custom object para JSON no Totalcross

Tags: java, json, totalcross

É possível serializar um Custom Object para JSON sem ter que inserir campo-a-campo, como por exemplo:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();                       
jsonObject.put("id", meuObjeto.id);
jsonObject.put("dt_sync", meuObjeto.dtSync);
jsonObject.put("dt_modif", meuObjeto.dtModif);
```

Tentei passar o objeto por parâmetro no construtor do JSONObject

```
JSONObject jsonPedido = new JSONObject(pedido);
```

Porém alguns valores são perdidos.

Em Java, Android etc.. é possível utilizar a lib JACKSON por exemplo pra gerar um Map do Objeto e converter o mesmo num JSON... 
Ou via annotations.. enfim..

Existe uma forma mais ágil de implementar essa serialização de Custom Object para um JSONObject no Totalcross?

Comment: Esse construtor espera que existam `getters` no objeto sendo serializado. Tem como compartilhar um exemplo completo, verificável e mínimo?

Comment: Esse comentário já explica o não funcionamento da tentativa através do uso do construtor do JSONObject. Pois nossos falso-POJOS não possuem métodos getters e setters..

Comment: Apenas ainda por dúvida.. não há uma classe que faça o oposto da JSONFactory?

Ou seja, converter um Java Object em Json Object? 
Neste caso seria através do construtor, pois o mesmo utilizaria os métodos getters através do reflection para popular um Json Object.. isso?

Comment: Então não funciona para a serialização via construtor do `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se você precisa ainda de uma solução, mas eu consegui fazer da seguinte forma:

```
public class AuthenticationDTO {

private String username;

private String password;

public AuthenticationDTO() {
}

public AuthenticationDTO(final String username, final String password) {
super();
this.username = username;
this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
return username;
}

public String getPassword() {
return password;
}    

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return "AuthenticationDTO [username=" + username + ", password=" + password + "]";
}
}
```

Utilizando o JSONObject, ele converteu meu objeto para JSON:

```
AuthenticationDTO authenticationDTO = new AuthenticationDTO("admin", "admin");
JSONObject requestJsonAutentication = new JSONObject(authenticationDTO);
System.out.println(authenticationDTO.toString());
```

Retornando meu JSON: {"password":"admin","username":"admin"}
Acredito que o "_" possa está influenciando na hora de converter, ou os campos do seu objeto não estão com os nomes corretos.

Comment: Comentário do AP: ["nossos falso-POJOS não possuem métodos getters e setters"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243672/converter-um-custom-object-para-json-no-totalcross#comment499345_243672)